# Rails 5 rake db:schema:load doesn't create tables or run initialize_schema_migrations_table() on postgres database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker-compose, rake, travis-ci

I am currently trying to set up my Rails 5.1.6 system tests (using ruby 2.3.7) on Travis CI. In my travis CI tests I am using docker-compose to connect my app to a postgres database. Before each of my system tests, I am running

`rake db:schema:load --trace`

to clear the database to a clean state. This works fine locally in my System Tests (use postgreSQL from my dev machine). However when I run my system tests with docker-compose which use a postgres container, my `rake db:schema:load --trace` output is not calling all the create table commands and therefore not clearing my database as expected. Here is the output:

```
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Invoke db:check_protected_environments (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:check_protected_environments
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM     "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
       (0.4ms)  SELECT "ar_internal_metadata"."value" FROM     "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1  [["key",     "environment"]]
       (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM     "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
   (0.3ms)  SELECT "ar_internal_metadata"."value" FROM     "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1  [["key",     "environment"]]
       (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM     "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
       (0.3ms)  SELECT "ar_internal_metadata"."value" FROM     "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1  [["key",     "environment"]]
** Execute db:schema:load
[4ed5f501-7177-49e5-973e-f49e0d91ff89] Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-03 22:28:21 +0000
```

I am expecting it to look like this:

```
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Invoke db:check_protected_environments (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:check_protected_environments
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
   (0.3ms)  SELECT "ar_internal_metadata"."value" FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1  [["key", "environment"]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
   (0.1ms)  SELECT "ar_internal_metadata"."value" FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1  [["key", "environment"]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
   (0.1ms)  SELECT "ar_internal_metadata"."value" FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1  [["key", "environment"]]
** Execute db:schema:load
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
  SQL (0.3ms)  CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "plpgsql"
   -> 0.0123s
-- create_table("builds", {:id=>:serial, :force=>:cascade})
```

followed by the rest of the create_table commands until my database schema is set.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.5.3
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  app:
    image: $DOCKER_USERNAME/vizzy:$TRAVIS_COMMIT
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        RAILS_MASTER_KEY: $RAILS_MASTER_KEY
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    environment:
      - RAILS_MASTER_KEY=$RAILS_MASTER_KEY
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - RAILS_ENV=ci_test
      - HEADLESS=yes
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
volumes:
  data:
    external: true
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Weird how my system tests are passing locally but not running with docker-compose